# Workflow Disconnection

Tags: snakemake

When running a workflow from the repo like:

`snakemake --use-conda -p --cluster-config cluster.yaml --cluster "qsub -l {cluster.l} -m {cluster.m} -N {cluster.N} -r {cluster.r} -V" --jobs 1`

My job starts but runs into a `urllib` related error (see below). I'm running v3.13.3 on a compute server. Any tips on how to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

```
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 469, in snakemake
force_use_threads=use_threads)
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 450, in execute
dag.create_conda_envs(dryrun=dryrun)
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 166, in create_conda_envs
hash = env.hash
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/conda.py", line 55, in hash
md5hash.update(self.content)
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/conda.py", line 38, in content
content = urlopen(env_file).read()
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "miniconda3/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
response = self._open(req, data) ...
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Comment: This is almost impossible to diagnose without further information. Do you refer to a conda environment via an HTTP(s) URL, or are you using the wrapper directive? If so, it looks like the resource is either not available or you have no network connection on the compute cluster.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the wrapper directive like so: `"0.17.3/bio/samtools/index"`.  I have no problem running locally using the "file://" syntax. I think it must be an issue with the way the cluster makes the connection as you say.

Comment: Yes. If you don't have internet access in the cluster (maybe you can ask the admin), you can always clone the wrapper repository to a local disk, and point your rules to that local url with `file://`.